# flutter firestore pagination with streambuilder

Tags: flutter, pagination, google-cloud-firestore, stream, stream-builder

I have a flutter app and have problem implementing pagination with streambuilder using firestore. Researched the topic and there are some answers to it but none solved my problem. My app is a social media app that needs realtime data. I need to retrieve limited data and then load more data if the user scroll down. How can I implement it with streams and streambuilder, not future and future builder; something similar to Facebook.

Comment: Same problem, did you find an answer yet?

Comment: Check this out https://www.filledstacks.com/post/how-to-perform-real-time-pagination-with-firestore/. I followed it and it worked.